# Direct proof that $g_t=\text{diag}(e^{t/m}I_m,e^{-t/n}I_n)$'s action on $\operatorname{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/{\operatorname{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)}$ is ergodic

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, homogeneous-spaces, haar-measure

I wonder if there are any direct proof that $g_t=\operatorname{diag}(e^{t/m}I_m,e^{-t/n}I_n)$'s action on $\operatorname{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/{\operatorname{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)}$ is ergodic (or even stronger, mixing). Here $I_n$ denote the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

The classical proof of this involves the Howe–Moore theorem, which uses Mautner's lemma and can be applied to much more general Lie groups. But I wonder in this concrete setting whether we could have a more simplified/elementary proof. Although I stated $(g_t)$ explicitly as a diagonal flow, I should mention that perhaps only the unboundedness of $(g_t)$ will be used, although $g_t$ being an unbounded diagonal flow might make the proof easier somehow.

---

Update: this should be true for any $t\ne 0$. So we can actually just fix $t=1$ and just prove that $g_1$ acts ergodically, which is equivalent to saying that the subgroup $(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ acts ergodically.

Note that for $\operatorname{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/{\operatorname{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)}$, there are relatively more explicit descriptions for the Haar measure (using Siegel domain/Iwasawa decomposition etc.). I am thinking maybe we can solve this by studying what kind of sets in this space have invariant measure under $g_1$, or any diagonal subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ that is not all $\pm 1$'s. If an open set in the basis has nontrivial measure, then $g_1$'s acts like stretching the set along one direction and shrinking it along another direction and it should change the Haar measure in some ways—that is my intuition.

Comment: That's not a research level question. Anyhow the usual Hopf argument gives you invariant under stable/unstable horospherical groups. This does not require ergodicity. You just need to show extra invariance under commuting central directions. Pick an ergodic component, use the ergodic theorem for $g_{t}$, pick your favorite generic point and show that it is preserved under any element from the center direction by commutation. Hence this ergodic component is preserved by $g_{t}$, horospherics $G_{a}^{\pm}$ and $AM$. Now just notice by Lie alg, that $G_{a}^{-}AMG_{a}^{+}$ is generating everything

Comment: @Asaf  My question is about how to prove directly "$g_t=\text{diag}(e^{t/m}I_m,e^{-t/n}I_n)$'s action on $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb R)/\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ is ergodic". What is the aim of your comment? Invariance of what under stable/unstable horospherical groups?

Comment: As I said, you conclude that every ergodic component which is $g_{t}$-invariant is invariant under the subgroup generated by $G_{a}^{-}AMG_{a}^{+}$, which is everything, hence by uniqueness of the Haar measure, every ergodic component is Haar.

The Hopf argument gives invariance of the general (a-priori not ergodic) measure under the strong stable/unstable foliations. Obviously this also applies to each ergodic component...

Comment: @NoOne Why don't you read Moore's 'Ergodicity of flows on homogeneous spaces'? :)

Comment: Probably a slightly easier argument that would work in many cases would go like this - one knows that any $g_{t}$-inv function is $G^{\pm}$ inv. One can consider maximal horosphericals (the abelianizations), of-course the function is invariant under them as well. Using commutators (from opposite root spaces), one may show that the function is invariant under the whole $A$ - the split Cartan. And actually in many many cases, the horosphericals will generate (i.e. in your case for m=2,n=1). The main trick is to consider commutators of $[n_{a+b},n_{-a}]$, etc...

Comment: Actually the shorter proof would always work for $SL_n$, no matter about your (m,n) as $SL_n$ is a SIMPLE group, and the Lie algebra generated by $Lie(G±)$ is an ideal. In the general semisimple case, one needs to be careful with the roots, etc... Probably the smart thing to do is simply to enumerate all the root spaces of the maximal horospherical subgroups and construct by hand the required spaces by the Lie brackets...

Comment: @Latimer Actually I did try to read Moore's paper myself and it is actually not quite self-contained, by citing many results of Borel and Mackey etc. Also I am just asking about the ergodicity, not mixing! I feel like for such specific setting there must be a more explicit and self-contained proof. Note that for $\operatorname{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\operatorname{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$, there are relatively more explicit descriptions for the Haar measure (Siegel domain etc.). I am thinking maybe we can solve this by studying what kind of sets in this space have invariant measure under $g_1$

Comment: @NoOne, my comments above, in view of the fact that $SL_{n}$ is a simple group, give a full proof of ergodicity in the lines of the Hopf argument. It's an interesting  question whether you can upgrade ergodicity to mixing, I will need to think about it. 

What you are proposing is not possible, there is a plethora of invariant measures (and sets) for the diagonal action (say in $SL_{2}$, the action is Bernoulli), including fractal ones of essentially any dimension between $1$ and full dimension.

Comment: @Asaf Maybe I am saying something stupid but the unbounded subgroup $(g_n)_{\mathbb Z}$ acts ergodically and I guess this should imply the generator $g_1$ is ergodic just from the definition?

Comment: I don't understand the statement ''unbounded subgroup'', unbounded subgroup of what?
It is correct that every unbounded subgroups act ergodically (and even mixingly), and that follows from say decay of matrix coefficients (which is rather ''direct proof'' but very technical, as it quantifies Howe-Moore). All the other proofs I can think of will definitely use some sort of Mautner phenomenon and fallback on ergodicity/mixing of $g_{t}$.

Comment: P.S. Even in the usual proofs of decay of matrix coefficients (say Cowling-Howe-Haagerup), one studies decay of the matrix coefficient under $g_{t}$, then extends by KAK decomposition. I think the estimates of Harish Chandra are also following the decay along the Cartan group (as it allows HC to get the differential equations).

Comment: @NoOne Pfft, how will you become the next big thing if you don't know $C^*$-algebras, Type I groups, structure theorems for semisimple groups. :p

Comment: @Asaf By unbounded I mean "non-compact". Subgroup of $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @NoOne , clearly $g_{n}$ is not a subgroup of $SL_{d}(\mathbb{Z})$. The fact that $g_{1}$ acts ergodically does not in general imply that $g_{n}$ is (say think of exchanging two points). It is true in the case of mixing (or in more generality - if your spectrum does not contain rational eigenvalues). I am still puzzled with one thing - how would you know that $g_{1}/g_{n}$ acts ergodically to begin with?

P.S. In general, for general $G$-actions, having an ergodic action does not mean that a subgroup acts ergodically (this is exactly the situation the Mautner phenomenon is trying to solve).

Comment: @Asaf sorry for my typo. Z should be R. Yes, the big group acts ergodically doesn't mean small ones act ergodically. And yes that is what Howe Moore theorem is giving. But I am thinking about maybe just directly proving that $g_1$ acts ergodically.

Comment: @NoOne, I think we are going in circles. I explained how one can deduce that $g_{1}$ acting ergodically based on the Hopf argument (and the fact that the horospherical groups generate $SL_{n}$ which is a simple group).